# Apache access logs - Is it possible to visit a page and not have apache log it?

Tags: php, apache

I have been fighting with hackers for over a month now and although I have closed several holes there is one issue that I am having a lot of trouble figuring out.

We have an "in house" developed CMS and I have recently put in login tracking across the board for the sole purpose of identifying if someone is logging in who shouldn't be. A couple times now someone has logged into a couple different sites (the CMS admin) however there is no forensic evidence in apache logs whatsoever despite the fact I have the log records from my CMS login validation process.

The hackers MO has been to login to the CMS and find a file uploader to upload/inject php shells and/or back doors. I have closed the holes involved but these logins continue to happen.

Could someone please help shine any light as to how someone could visit a web page or whatever and not leave any trace in any apache logs?

We are using Apache 2.2 with PHP 5.3 on a WHM/cpanel platform.

Comment: probably they got root and are changing the apache logs?

Answer (score 0):

If your box has been hacked, you may not be able to trust the logs - the hacker may have changed them.

I think, if you want a definite answer, the best idea is to mirror your network port to another computer, and traffic dump until you see something suspicious, then look in the traffic logs to see what happened.

Depending on how good the hacker is, you might get away with running a packet capture on the box in question - it might not get noticed. But take it with a grain of salt.

The other possibility is that the hacker has manually set a cookie (assuming you use cookies for tracking logged in information). They will appear to "be logged in", without having logged in.